# Azure kubernetes - Number of Nginx controllers?

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am going to deploy an application on Azure kubernetes with the following configuration

1. Kind : service
2. Replicas : 4
3. Horizontal pod scaling : ~8
4. Ingress : Nginx Ingress controller

As I have the Horizontal Pod scaling, when the load increases number of service Pod will increase automatically. However, should I also need to increase the frontier Nginx controller, if so, how would I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you don't have to add more Ingress controllers when autoscaling.

One Nginx Ingress controller is enough and you don't have to add/configure more in a situation when more application pods will be created. You just need one controller.

If you need to know more details regarding the HPA consider visiting the official sources [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/).